# sqlalchemy core: Execute Multiple Statements gives StatementError, memoryview error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to populate a table called puppies using sqlalchemy core. Here is the table definition:

```
puppies = Table('puppies', metadata,
            Column('name', String),
            Column('date_of_birth', types.DateTime),
            Column('breed', String),
            Column('gender', String),
            Column('weight', Integer),
            Column('pic', types.Blob), ## This is the problem
            Column('shelter_id', Integer, ForeignKey('shelters.id'))
            )
```

Below is the error log

```
Error:
    return DBAPIBinary(value)
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: memoryview: str object does not have the buffer interface (original cause: TypeError: memoryview: str object does not have the buffer interface)
```

python: 3.4 sqlalchemy: 0.9

does this error have to do with byte strings?

Solution: changed types.Blob to types.NullType

Why does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on the SQLAlchemy IRC channel, this is because of unicode. A Python3 string is a unicode string; you need to use a bytes object or another object supporting the buffer protocol if you want to use the BLOB type.

SQLAlchemy also provides the UnicodeText type for large unicode strings.

NullType "works" because SQLAlchemy just passes it straight through and trusts the database driver to do the right thing with it, which apparently it does in this case.